# call parent members via this pointer

Tags: c++, c++17

Long code, but it's quite simple.

```
class CDbAccessor {
public:
    virtual std::string GetValue() = 0;
};

class CPagingDbAccessor : public CDbAccessor {
public:
    virtual std::string GetValue() override {
        return "CPagingDbAccessor::GetValue()";
    }
};

class CSpecialDbAccessor : public CDbAccessor {
public:
    virtual std::string GetValue() override {
        return "CSpecialDbAccessor::GetValue()";
    }
};

class CSpecialPagingDbAccessor : public CSpecialDbAccessor {
    CDbAccessor* pCurrentAccessor;
    CPagingDbAccessor m_pagingAccessor;
    int currentTable;
public:
    enum { etPerson, etCompany };

    void SetCurrentTable(int entity) {
        currentTable = entity;
        switch (entity)
        {
        case etPerson:
            pCurrentAccessor = &m_pagingAccessor; break;
        case etCompany:
            pCurrentAccessor = (CSpecialDbAccessor*)this; break;//When the data is small, we still use the orignal CSpecialDbAccessor, but it's not working.
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    virtual std::string GetValue() override {
        return pCurrentAccessor->GetValue();
    }
};


int main(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    CSpecialPagingDbAccessor accessor;
    accessor.SetCurrentTable(CSpecialPagingDbAccessor::etCompany);
    cout << accessor.GetValue() << endl;
    accessor.SetCurrentTable(CSpecialPagingDbAccessor::etPerson);
    cout << accessor.GetValue() << endl; //expect to call CSpecialDbAccessor::GetValue(), but it still calls itself. dead loop.
}
```

We have interface `CDbAccessor`, and 2 derived classes `CPagingDbAccessor` and `CSpecialDbAccessor`. There are lots of sepcial processings in CSpecialDbAccessor. Now, some tables are huge,we have to add paging function to CSpecialDbAccessor as well.

Another possible solution is

```
class CSpecialPagingDbAccessor : public CSpecialDbAccessor, public CPagingDbAccessor{};
```

But it involves `Diamond Inheritance Problem`, we all dismiss this solution.

As in the current solution, we expect the second `accessor.GetValue()` output `CSpecialDbAccessor::GetValue()`, but it calls itself and causes dead loop.

One possible solution is,

```
virtual std::string GetValue() override {
    switch (currentTable) {
    case tbPerson:
        return m_pagingAccessor.GetValue();
    case tbCompany:
        return CSpecialDbAccessor::GetValue();
    }
}
```

But considering the data is huge, the check with each data entry would affect the perfermance.

Do you have any good idea?

Comment: You seem need `CDbAccessor* CSpecialPagingDbAccessor::m_accessor`, and `class CSpecialPagingDbAccessor` does not need the inheritence.

Comment: "we all dismiss this solution" Who are those "we all"? Never met any of them.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI, just my colleagues :D

Comment: Perfect match for `std::variant` and no virtual function design criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use full composition:

```
class CSpecialPagingDbAccessor : public CDbAccessor {
    CDbAccessor* pCurrentAccessor;
    CPagingDbAccessor m_pagingAccessor;
    CSpecialDbAccessor m_specialAccessor;
    int currentTable;
public:
    enum { etPerson, etCompany };

    void SetCurrentTable(int entity) {
        currentTable = entity;
        switch (entity)
        {
        case etPerson: pCurrentAccessor = &m_pagingAccessor; break;
        case etCompany: pCurrentAccessor = &m_specialAccessor; break;
        default: break;
        }
    }
    std::string GetValue() override { return pCurrentAccessor->GetValue(); }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/65G9nd69a)